# Mapping a dictionary to a dataframe not working correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping

I am trying to map a dictionary to a dataframe. I dug through some code and pieced together what I thought would work, but the code isn't running. Can anyone help with getting this to map?

Top15 is an existing dataframe with Country as the Index.

```
ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia', 
              'United States':'North America', 
              'Japan':'Asia', 
              'United Kingdom':'Europe', 
              'Russian Federation':'Europe', 
              'Canada':'North America', 
              'Germany':'Europe', 
              'India':'Asia',
              'France':'Europe', 
              'South Korea':'Asia', 
              'Italy':'Europe', 
              'Spain':'Europe', 
              'Iran':'Asia',
              'Australia':'Australia', 
              'Brazil':'South America'}




Top15['Continent'] = Top15['Country'].map(ContinentDict)
```

Comment: Without raw data, code for your df then this is just speculative, you need to post data and code in order for others to reproduce this

Comment: What's not working, can you show your inputs and expected output, e.g. what is `Top15`

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ought to work. Here's an example:

```
In [1]:Top15 = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['France','Brazil', 'Canada', 'Japan']})
      Top15
Out[1]:
  Country
0  France
1  Brazil
2  Canada
3   Japan
```

Now you can indeed use [pd.Series.map](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) using a dict as argument:

```
In [2]: Top15['Continent'] = Top15['Country'].map(ContinentDict)
        Top15
Out[2]:
  Country      Continent
0  France         Europe
1  Brazil  South America
2  Canada  North America
3   Japan           Asia
```

---

### Update: now that we know Top15 is indexed by country

The problem is that `index.map` doesn't allow a dict as an argument. But you can do either of these:

```
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 696 µs per loop
Top15['Continent'] = Top15.index.to_series().map(ContinentDict)

# 1000 loops, best of 3: 722 µs per loop
Top15['Continent'] = pd.Series(Top15.index).map(ContinentDict)
```

Or much faster:

```
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 156 µs per loop
Top15['Continent'] = Top15.index.map(lambda x: ContinentDict[x])
```

Comment: Top15 is already an existing dataframe with Country as the Index. Shouldn't pd.Series.map work already?

Comment: See my update with three possibilities including profiling