# Pandas remap or replace based on dictionary, but dictionary value pairs are in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to map or replace values in a Pandas data frame based on value pairs in a dictionary. The value pairs are in a list, and I want to split the items into their own columns. There are always only two items in the value pair list.

**Stand-alone example**

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3, 4], "cat": ["text1", "text3", "text1", "text4"]})

mydict = {
    "text1": ["a15", "b3"],
    "text2": ["a6", "b1"],
    "text3": ["a3", "b3"],
    "text4": ["a1", "b12"],
}

display(mydf)
```

[image]

**Desired result**

[image]

**Efforts**

Based on [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432315/pandas-replace-column-values-by-dictionary-keys-if-they-are-in-dictionary-valu) I tried the following:

```
new_map = {str(x): str(k) for k, v in mydict.items() for x in v}
mydf['left'] = mydf['cat']
mydf['left'].map(new_map)
```

Which doesn't work, it returns this:

[image]

I also tried the following ([based on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849340/mapping-a-dictionary-to-a-dataframe-not-working-correctly)):

```
new_map = {str(x): str(k) for k, v in mydict.items() for x in v}
mydf['left'] = mydf.index.map(lambda x: new_map[x])
```

Which resulted in the error `KeyError: 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) to convert `mydict` directly to a DataFrame then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to `mydf`:

```
mydf = mydf.join(
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict, orient='index', columns=['left', 'right']),
    on='cat'
)
```

`mydf`:

```
   x    cat left right
0  1  text1  a15    b3
1  2  text3   a3    b3
2  3  text1  a15    b3
3  4  text4   a1   b12
```

Answer (score 3):

this can be done by merge.

- convert dict to a list
- merge by cat key

```py
mylist = [[key,mydict[key][0],mydict[key][1]] for key in mydict]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(mylist,columns=['cat','left','right'])
df2

df = pd.merge(mydf,df2,on='cat',how='left')
```

```
    x   cat     left    right
0   1   text1   a15     b3
1   2   text3   a3      b3
2   3   text1   a15     b3
3   4   text4   a1      b12
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate dataframe from the mapping and join back to the original dataframe via a join, or concat:

```
    mapped = (mydf.cat
                  .map(mydict)
                  .apply(pd.Series)
                  .set_axis(['left', 'right'], axis='columns'))
    
      left right
    0  a15    b3
    1   a3    b3
    2  a15    b3
    3   a1   b12
```

Join back to the main df

```
 mydf.join(mapped)

   x    cat left right
0  1  text1  a15    b3
1  2  text3   a3    b3
2  3  text1  a15    b3
3  4  text4   a1   b12
```

You can skip the verbose option above with this solution from @HenryEcker:

```
mydf[['left', 'right']] = mydf.cat.map(mydict).apply(pd.Series)
```

Comment: Seems like `mydf[['left', 'right']] = mydf.cat.map(mydict).apply(pd.Series)` could also work here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Take advantage of the fact that not much is needed to transform `mydict` into a dataframe:

```
mydf.merge(pd.DataFrame(mydict,
                        index=['left', 'right']).T,
           left_on='cat',
           right_index=True,
           how='left', sort=False
          )
```

output:

```
   x    cat left right
0  1  text1  a15    b3
1  2  text3   a3    b3
2  3  text1  a15    b3
3  4  text4   a1   b12
```